# Loop in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Instead of using fileList.map(), I want to put it in for loop and setTimeout(500) for every single loop. How can I do it ?

```
 const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ fileList }) => (
      <div>
        {
        fileList.map((file, index) => (
          <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={file} />
        ))
        }
      </div>
    ))
```

Comment: May I ask what's the reason for that?

Comment: I want to upload a list of image, but I dont want to show all of them at the same time, instead, I want to show them sequently

Comment: Use state with `visibleItems` and add there item from `fileList` every 500ms

Comment: Have you considered using some animation library to do such thing? I would also suggest to use pure CSS transform & transition combo

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const ITEMS_TO_ADD_IN_EACH_TIMEOUT = 50

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ fileList }) => {
   const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          setVisibleItems([fileList.slice(0, visibleItems.length + ITEMS_TO_ADD_IN_EACH_TIMEOUT)])
      }, 500);

      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
   })

   return (
      <div>
         {
            visibleItems.map((file, index) => (
              <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={file} />
            ))
         }
      </div>
   ))
}
```

Comment: I pasted it in but I got "fileList is declared but its value is never used"

Comment: Try it now. Notice the variable `ITEMS_TO_ADD_IN_EACH_TIMEOUT` and how it's being used in `setVisibleItems`

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to create a new array which should contain the items which are currently visible.

Then do a simple setTimeout which will call a recursive function every 500ms that will add one element to the visible array.

```
 const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ fileList }) => {
  const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    function displayNext(next) {
      setVisibleItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, fileList[next]]);
      if (++next < fileList.length) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          displayNext(next);
        }, 500);
      }
    }

    displayNext(0);
  }, []);

  return (
     <div>
        {
           visibleItems.map((file, index) => (
             <SortableItem key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={file} />
           ))
        }
     </div>
  )});
```

Let me know if works!

Comment: I pasted it in but I got "fileList is declared but its value is never used". Your func use fileList as param but don't use. Can you please change it ?

Comment: Try it now, make sure you are using it in the right way and the fileList is an array

Comment: But I don't see where you use fileList in your code ? How can it run ?

Comment: I got this ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function```
at this line ```const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([]);```

Comment: I think the problem is in useState([]) object, can you show me more details ?

Comment: Have a look at this code sandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-banach-wowl3?file=/src/App.js